# Javascript: How to turn the time (stored as a fraction) into a readable string?

Tags: javascript, time, formatting

I have the time stored as a fraction (done so it can be displayed on a graph), e.g. 15.5 is 3.30pm and 23.25 is 11.15pm. I need to turn those numbers into strings in the format HH:MM:SS. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```js
var fraction = 14.5;
var hours = Math.floor(fraction); // extract the hours (in 24 hour format)
var mins = 60 * (fraction - hours); // calculate the minutes
t = new Date(); // create a date/time object

t.setHours(hours); // set the hours
t.setMinutes(mins); // set the mins
console.log(t.toTimeString()); //show it
```

or completely manual

```js
var fraction = 14.5;
var hours = Math.floor(fraction);
var mins = 60 * (fraction - hours);
var ampm = ((fraction % 24) < 12) ? 'am' : 'pm';

formatted = ('0' + hours % 12).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + mins).substr(-2) + ':00 ' + ampm;
console.log(formatted);
```

***Update***

And a version with seconds as well..

```js
var fraction = 14.33;
var hours = Math.floor(fraction);
var allseconds = 3600 * (fraction - hours);
var minutes = Math.floor(allseconds / 60);
var seconds = Math.floor(allseconds % 60);
var ampm = ((fraction % 24) < 12) ? 'am' : 'pm';

formatted = ('0' + hours % 12).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + minutes).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + seconds).substr(-2) + ' ' + ampm;
console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: The fraction also stores seconds as well as minutes, but that looks like what I need so far

Comment: @Sarah, added version with seconds :)

Answer (score 9):

```
var fraction = 23.5;

var date = new Date(2000, 1, 1); // use any date as base reference
date.setUTCSeconds(fraction * 3600); // add number of seconds in fractional hours
```

Then use a date formatting script such as [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format), or [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) if you're not fond or formatting and padding.

```
date.format("HH:MM:ss"); // 23:30:00
```

[See an example](http://jsfiddle.net/9VuGv/1). I'm using the formatting function from [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).

Comment: +1 yes, Steven Leviathin's date formatter is brilliant for flexible date formatting in JS: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: @Gaby - I recently discovered that JavaScript set* functions handle overflow very nicely and put me in awe :) .. @fearoffours - It is indeed an awesome lightweight library for formatting dates when Date.js feels a little too much  :)

Answer (score 0):

Manual function:

```
        var time = function(num) {
          if(num < 0 || num >= 24) {throw "Invalid number");}
          var x = num > 13 ? num - 12 : num;
          var h = Math.floor(x);
          var min = x - h;
          var ampm = num >= 12 && num < 24 ? "pm" : "am";

          return (h + ":" + Math.floor(min * 60) + ampm);
        };
```

Tests:

```
        time(13.40); // 1:24pm
        time(11.25); // 11:15pm
        time(12.50); // 12:30pm
        time(23.50); // 11:30pm
        time(0.50);  // 0:30am
        time(24.00); // error!!
```